# How to make sure callback has been called with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm testing my angular application using Protractor.
In my test, I want to click on button1 and make sure that the callback connected to this button has been called.

How can I do this?

In general, how can I make sure in tests that some function has been called?

Answer (score 0):

This is *out of the Protractor's scope*. When you write your end-to-end tests in Protractor you are typically **thinking as a real user** of your application - for instance: "if I click this button I should see this confirmation popup", "if I follow this link I should get to the Contact Us page".

Comment: but the protractor allows me to evaluate the scope that I am in.